# StackPanel with User Controls in another User Control in Xaml Windows Phone

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8, user-controls

How Can I add child items to StackPanel in UserControl from C# code? Should I create something like DependencyProperty for it?

As it is easy to set Properties like Text for TextBlock in my UserControl, I have no idea how can I add items to StackPanel when using CodeBehind to do it dynamicaly.

Comment: Don't operate on controls in code behind. Use `ItemsControl` and bind its `ItemsSource` to some `ObservableCollection` and operate on that instead

Answer (score 1):

`StackPanel` are only meant to be used for the most basic layout situations. It is far better using some kind of `ListBox` or `ItemsControl` depending on your requirements. You could add a collection `DependencyProperty` to your `UserControl` and do something like this:

In `UserControl`:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding YourCollectionDependencyProperty, RelativeSource={
    RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type YourPrefix:YourUserControl}}}" ... />
```

Then you could data bind another collection property to the `UserControl` from outside the control:

Outside `UserControl`:

```
<YourPrefix:YourUserControl YourCollectionDependencyProperty="{Binding Items}" ... />
```

Then adding new items to be displayed in the `UserControl` is as simple as adding items to the `Items` collection:

```
Items.Add(someNewObject);
```

Please read the [Data Binding Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN for further information on data binding.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do something like this (this is just a sample):

```
TextBlock printTextBlock = new TextBlock();
printTextBlock.Text = "Hello, World!";
//MainStackPanel below is the name given to your control in xaml
MainStackPanel.Children.Add(printTextBlock);
```

Sources:

- [Programatically Adding Items to StackPanel](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/vstudio/en-US/531f8bc7-4d62-464a-8180-beddaa46cb7d/programatically-adding-items-to-stackpanel)